# Redux store reset when navigating (after I've refactored reducer)

Tags: redux, refactoring, state, react-navigation, reducers

I am trying the refactor my reducer into two "sub" reducers and combine them before exporting to store.js. However, when I am navigating in my app the state of my notificationReducer gets reseted, and not the other reducers. I am unsure of what might be the problem and I've followed the guide (sort of) from redux.js.org => 
[Separating Data Handling by Domain](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/RefactoringReducersExample.html#separating-data-handling-by-domain)

Any thoughts or tips on how you've refactored reducers?

---

**notificationReducer.js**

```
import {
  FETCHING_NOTIFICATION_STATUS, // NOTIFICATION
  FETCHING_NOTIFICATION_STATUS_SUCCESS,
  FETCHING_NOTIFICATION_STATUS_FAILURE,
  FETCHING_NOTIFICATION_DATA, // NOTIFICATION
  FETCHING_NOTIFICATION_DATA_SUCCESS,
  FETCHING_NOTIFICATION_DATA_FAILURE,
  FETCHING_MARK_NOTIFICATION_AS_UNSEEN, // NOTIFICATION
  FETCHING_MARK_NOTIFICATION_AS_UNSEEN_SUCCESS,
  FETCHING_MARK_NOTIFICATION_AS_UNSEEN_FAILURE
} from '../Actions/actionTypes'

const fetchingData = {
  isFetching: false,
  dataFetched: false,
  error: false,
  errorMsg: '',
}

const initialState = {
  notificationStatus: {
    ...fetchingData,
    hasNotifications: false,
  },
  notificationData: {
    ...fetchingData,
    data: [],
  }, 
  markNotification: {
    ...fetchingData,
    isUnseen: false,
  }, 
}

const { notificationStatus, notificationData, markNotification } = initialState

const notificationStatusReducer = (state = notificationStatus, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCHING_NOTIFICATION_STATUS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
      }
    case FETCHING_NOTIFICATION_STATUS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        dataFetched: true,
        hasNotifications: action.data,
      }
    case FETCHING_NOTIFICATION_STATUS_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        error: true,
        errorMsg: action.errorMsg,
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}

const notificationDataReducer = (state = notificationData, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCHING_NOTIFICATION_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      }
    case FETCHING_NOTIFICATION_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        dataFetched: true,
        data: action.data,
      }
    case FETCHING_NOTIFICATION_DATA_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        error: true,
        errorMsg: action.errorMsg,
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}

const markNotificationReducer = (state = markNotification, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCHING_MARK_NOTIFICATION_AS_UNSEEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      }
    case FETCHING_MARK_NOTIFICATION_AS_UNSEEN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        dataFetched: true,
        isUnseen: true,
      }
    case FETCHING_MARK_NOTIFICATION_AS_UNSEEN_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        error: true,
        errorMsg: action.errorMsg,
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}

const notificationReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  return {
      notificationStatusReducer : notificationStatusReducer(state.notificationStatus, action),
      notificationDataReducer : notificationDataReducer(state.notificationStatus, action),
      markNotificationReducer : markNotificationReducer(state.markNotification, action),
  }
}

export default notificationReducer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`combineReducers`](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UsingCombineReducers.html) for such things. So your `notificationReducer` should be the combination of yours three reducers.

```
const notificationReducer = combineReducers({
  notificationStatusReducer,
  notificationDataReducer,
  markNotificationReducer 
})
```

Hope it will help